# get javascript data from web page in mountain lion

Tags: javascript, objective-c, webview, osx-mountain-lion

I am extrating from a web page dynamic values generated by javascript and it worked fine on OS X Lion but failed on Mountain Lion 10.8.1 (I get empty string).
Here is the code in my controller :

```
-(void) addValue:(id) sender  {
  NSString *value = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.getElementById('xxx').textContent"];
}

- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
[self addValue:self];
}

 - (void) getjavascriptValue {
[[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"htmlPagePath"] ]]];
}
```

webView is declared as IBOutlet WebView *webView; and I made the connections of webView and frameLoadDelegate to my controller with Interface Builder.
Your help will be very much appreciated

Comment: the html page with javascript data is displayed OK in the webView and it is stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString which returns empty string. I checked javascript is enabled in Interface Builder

Comment: Apple ask me to issue a bug report : looks like a mountain Lion bug